# What messaging technologies in windows-ce for guaranteed msg delivery?

Tags: windows-ce, msmq, audit, amqp

We are building a windows-ce (6.0R3) based device that requires guaranteed and audit-ready message delivery (including store & forward) up to and down from the cloud.

I have been looking for choices beyond:

- MSMQ
- a proprietary solution (what our
  prototype device is using)
- AMQP (I have not found any RabbitMQ clients for CE, by example)

**... are there any others?**

We will be transporting sensitive data (who isn't?!?!) over a public network, and large scale options are required. Anything running on an embedded device will be performance sensitive too.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Qpid (http://qpid.apache.org) has a C++ client that I ported to Windows; it could also be ported to CE without much trouble. Apache Qpid C++ runs AMQP 0-10; if you require interop with RabbitMQ broker (AMQP 0-8?), this may be a problem.